# Classic ASP accessing an Array of Byte and converting it into a string

Tags: post, asp-classic, jscript

To test, I am sending the data using curl like so:

```
curl -XPOST http://test.local/kms/test.asp --data "{\"a\":1212321}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

In test.asp I have something like this:

```
var byteArray = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);
```

From there I try to convert each byte to a character and append it to a string, however accessing the information seems to be the issue. 
This is one attempt I have tried:

```
 var str = "";
 for (var x = 0; x < Request.TotalBytes; x++) {
     str += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[x]);
 }
```

When I check in visual studio, the data looks like this:

[image: display of Array of Bytes]

Is there a better way to get data from a request?

Answer (score 3):

> Accessing an Array of Byte and converting it into a string

For server-side JScript, and using your curl POST example above, try this:

```
var postData = null;
with (Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")) {
    Type = 1; // adTypeBinary
    Open();
    Write(Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes));
    Position = 0;
    Type = 2; // adTypeText
    Charset = "iso-8859-1";
    postData = ReadText();
    Close();
}
if (postData) {
    var json = null;
    eval("json = " + postData);
    Response.Write(json.a);
}
```

This solution uses the ADODB.Stream object to write-in the binary data from the Request, reset the position back to the beginning of the stream, then convert the binary data to a properly encoded string by reading it into a variable (postData).  If postData exists, evaluate the JSON string as-is, then use it.

---

> Is there a better way to get data from a request?

Perhaps.  You could POST the data as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', then simply access the variables using Request.Form("a").

For example, try changing your curl POST command to:

```
curl -XPOST http://test.local/kms/test.asp --data "a=1212321" -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Then update your server-side ASP JScript code to resemble:

```
var str = Request.Form("a");
Response.Write(str);
```

Hope this is helpful.